# 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use keras to train a RL model, in the loss function, I am using tf.py_function to call a model trained using pytorch, then I came across this error.

The tensorflow version is 1.15.

Comment: Please let us see the code.

Comment: Hi yan, could you maybe provide the code you used? In general using pytorch models in tensorflow is not quite straight-forward, doing all in either framework would probably be easier.